# Creating a pandas Series with numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working with pandas timeseries, where there are timestamps as index and NaN as values. My backend developer told me he would love it if I would not have to import pandas in my script. Managed to replace it everywhere except for that one. How can I do this with numpy?

```
series=pandas.Series(data=None, index=complete_index)

print(series)
```

Returns:

```
2019-10-15 16:14:19.440769+00:00   NaN
2019-10-15 16:14:24.762119+00:00   NaN
                                    ..
2019-10-16 16:13:49.470747+00:00   NaN
2019-10-16 16:14:19.440769+00:00   NaN
Length: 2990, dtype: float64
```

Comment: what is the desire output? you cannot obtain a series object with numpy, but you can create an empty array and then assign complete_index to 1st column

Comment: How much are you using pandas? Replacing it with numpy could get awkward.

Comment: @Benoit de Menthière sounds good! But how do you create an empty array exactly? Does it have to be the right row size before assigning the index?

Comment: Depending on what you want to put in the `nans` later, using two arrays is better. Numpy can (but is not optimized to) handle different data types in the same array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want an array, you can use:

`arr = np.full((2990, 2), np.nan, dtype = 'datetime64')
arr[:,0] = complete_index`

Comment: I get the response:

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime' (its referring to  "arr[:, 0] = complete_index"

Comment: interestingly, if I use " arr[:, 0] = complete_index.astype()" I get: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2019-10-17 07:50:26.950499+00:00'" :)

Comment: depending on what the 2nd column is going to be filled with, you may choose dtype=object